# Continue a while loop until char == EOF

Tags: c, string

```
while( (c = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF ){
    count++;
    if (count == lineLen - 1){
        moreChars = (char*) realloc(line, lineLen *=2);

        if(moreChars == NULL){
            puts("Error allocating for moreChars.");
            free(moreChars);
            exit(-69);
        }
        else
            line = moreChars;
    }
    line[count - 1] = c;
}
```

That is my code. My problem is that when the user enters (ctrl + d) to end the loop they have to enter it twice ie, to end loop user types (ctrl+d)(ctrl+d).

sample input:

> hi there you guy dood (ctrl+d) (ctrl+d)

ideal input:

> hi there you guy dood (ctrl+d)

To make it more clear:

I want the user to only have to enter (ctrl+d) once to end the loop, and can't figure out why the use has to enter (ctrl+d)(ctrl+d) to end loop.

Thanks.

Comment: I have code appending a null character to string outside loop and all that. Only problem is within this code fragment imo. Will supply other code if necessary.

Comment: make sure `c` is an `int`

Comment: ^D isn't technically EOF, it tells the shell to flush its buffer, as does a newline. If you flush the buffer while it is empty, that's when you get EOF. Therefore, if you press return at the end of your text you will only have to press ^D once.

Comment: c is an int. extra chars for post.

Comment: @ughoavgfhw has the right answer (and should post it as one).  MoonFan - try `echo abcde | ./example` (or whatever your program is called) to see it working the way you expect.

Answer (score 0):

How is `c` defined?  fgetc() returns an int, and EOF is an int.  If c is a char, they won't match.

Comment: This answer is potentially useful, but `EOF` is often `-1`, so if `char` is signed on his system it may well work fine.  It's certainly not the answer to the OP's question, in any case.

Comment: c is an int. extra chars for post.